# Ext, Extensions and homomorphisms between them

Tags: homological-algebra

Say that we have $R$-modules (let's assume over a commutative ring $R$). Consider extensions of a module $A$ by a module $C$, so that we have short exact sequences:
$0 \rightarrow B  \rightarrow^i E  \rightarrow C \rightarrow 0.$
We say that two extensions are equivalent if they can be fitted into a commutative diagram:

$\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad$
[image: aextensions]

Now, if we have two $R$-module homomorphisms $f\colon B\to C$, $g\colon B\to C$, we can from f and g indivudally create new extensions, where the middle term is the pushout of $f$ and $i$, resp. $g$ and $i$.

When will these two homomorphisms determine the same extension, that is, when will we be given an equivalence of extensions (as in the definition before this)?

I'm working through a problem set that says that this happens if and only if $f-g$ can be written as 
$i\colon B\to E$, followed by a homomorphism $E\to C$, but I can't see why this should be true, if the middle term E is not projective.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need projectivity of $E$ because you have sufficiently many push-out diagrams and short exact sequences around.

---

Let us fix the notation first. Form the push-out under $i$ and $f$ to obtain the diagram

```
    i       i'
B >---> E --->> A
|       |       |
|f      |f'     |1
V   j   V   j'  v
C >---> P --->> A
```

and form the push-out under $i$ and $g$ to obtain the diagram

```
    i       i'
B >---> E --->> A
|       |       |
|g      |g'     |1
V   k   V   k'  v
C >---> Q --->> A.
```

We want to show that the extensions `C >-> P ->> A` and `C >-> Q ->> A` are equivalent if and only if there exists a morphism `m: E -> C` such that `mi = g - f`.

---

To say that `C >-> P ->> A` and `C >-> Q ->> A` are equivalent is to say that there is an isomorphism `l: P -> Q` such that

```
    j       j'  
C >---> P --->> A
|       |       |
|1      |l      |1
V   k   V   k'  v
C >---> Q --->> A
```

commutes. Consider the morphism `g'-lf': E -> Q`. We have

```
k'(g'-lf') = k'g' - k'lf' = i' - j'f' = 0
```

so that `(g'-lf') = km` for a unique morphism `m: E -> C` since `k = ker k'`. Now notice that

```
kmi = (g' - lf')i = g'i - lf'i = kg - ljf = k (g - f)
```

so that the fact that `k` is a monomorphism gives that `mi = g-f`, as we wanted.

---

Conversely, suppose there is a morphism `m: E -> C` such that `mi = g-f`. Then

```
kf = k (g - mi) = kg - kmi = g'i - kmi = (g' - km) i
```

so that we have a commutative square

```
    i    
B >---> E
|       |
|f      |g'-km
V   k   V
C >---> Q
```

Applying the push-out property of `BECP` to that square we get a unique morphism `l: P -> Q` such that `k = lj` and `g'-km = lf'` and I claim that the diagram

```
    j       j'  
C >---> P --->> A
|       |       |
|1      |l      |1
V   k   V   k'  v
C >---> Q --->> A
```

commutes. For the left hand square this is given and for the right hand square notice that

```
(k'l - j') f' = k'lf' - j'f' = k' (g' - km) - i' = k'g' - i' = 0
```

and

```
(k'l - j') j = k'lj = k'k = 0
```

so that `(k'l - j')[j f'] = [0 0]` and this implies that `k'l-j' = 0` because the morphism `[j f']: C+E -->> P` is an epimorphism, as `BECP` is a push-out by hypothesis. It follows from the five lemma that the two extensions `C >-> P ->> A` and `C >-> Q ->> B` are equivalent.

---

It is a good exercise to show that a similar argument applied to an appropriate square (I'll let you find the morphism `(?)` yourself)

```
    i
B >---> E
|       |
|g      |(?)
V   j   V
C >---> P
```

and exploiting the push-out property of `BECQ` yields a morphism `l': Q -> P` which is inverse to `l: P -> Q`.